# A contradicting riddle

Tags: riddle

> I will point the way
>   
> Though if I point at you
>   
> It might be your last day
>   
> If my speed is true
>   
>   
> When in flight I scare
>   
> In liquid I have one aim
>   
> Sometimes I flare
>   
> Then wood will flame

> What am I?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the answer is

> Arrow

I will point the way

> Arrows are used as direction markers

Though if I point at you 
It might be your last day 
If my speed is true

> If struck by an arrow, you may die

When in flight I scare

> Arrows in flight can make a sort of buzzing sound.  Or people may simply be afraid of getting hit

In liquid I have one aim

> Underwater arrows or harpoons are only used for hunting fish

Sometimes I flare 
Then wood will flame

> Sometimes flaming arrows are used to burn wooden structures

Comment: Correct! New someone would get it, probably a bit too easy

Answer (score 1):

Idea:

> You are a weapon

Explanation:

> Weapons are pointed at targets.
>  If a weapon is pointed at you, it will indeed be your last day if the speed of the bullet is true.
>  In flight, bullets from the weapons do scare.
>  Suggested by Sleafar: Speargun for the "In liquid I have one aim".
>  Muzzles of guns flare when fired.
>  Wood will flame if shot at by a flamethrower...

Comment: Actually I meant [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speargun).

Comment: Sorry, you're on the right track but wrong weapon - it can be a weapon but it can be something else so I can't accept 'a weapon' as the answer

Comment: You are looking for something more specific?

Comment: Whoever downvoted, please can you tell me why? What can I improve in my answer?

Comment: If it wasn't clear enough hes said: (I'm paraphrasing) "Lorem isum dolor sit amet, consectetr adipiscing lit. Donec em ipsum, volupat eu congue  uscpit, accumsan vlutpat ate. Crs ultrice letus magna, quis iaculis sapin sceleisque a."

Comment: No it's not clear at all. I don't do latin, I'm afraid.